# Updating MonoDevelop 3.0.3.5 On Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, monodevelop

I just installed Monodevelop 3.0.3.2 on a Windows XP VM but I'm getting an error once I try to update:

[image]

Is MonoDevelop 3 supported on Windows XP?  Would I have more success building from source?

Comment: you might need latest mono version.

Comment: I know this is unrelated, at least in terms of OS, but my mac OSX 10.5.8 does not support MD 3.0 series, it took me a long time to search that out. I tried to look about windows XP, but I've not found anything definitive yet. CHEERS